# malloc_info gives malloc_stats 'system bytes’ but not ‘in use bytes’

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc, glibc

In glibc 2.15 (compiled with gcc 4.7.2) I fail to get parts of `malloc_stats` info with `malloc_info`. While *system bytes* and *in use bytes* per arena are showed with `malloc_stats` (unfortunately only to stderr) the `malloc_info` function does not give this information, but only *system bytes* (xml way).

Old mallinfo does not work well for arenas, but only for main arena. How do I get `malloc_stats` data in my program instead of printed out to stderr?

Comment: Have a look at the source code, all the info is so specific to the glibc implementation and version that you will need it anyways to interpret it

Comment: Thank you. I already took a look but I wonder how can it be that available data in earlier glibc versions (2.5) is not available in more recent like 2.15 or newer.

Comment: most likely due to (which is also the claimed reason to now use resource friendly xml) changes in the allocator itself. It has evolved a lot in the last decade.

Comment: that is not reasonable as the data is there using malloc_stats. only problem is that output of malloc_stats goes to stderr and there is no api to get it as a return value or as function argument. In the past (glibc 2.5) there was api more_malloc_stats for this but it is not there any more.